# Lotus Domino: Logging an imported text file

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I have an Agent that imports document from text file. So the user requires me to record the imports in a document, including the time it was imported, number of imported documents, fails and the reason why. I kinda get the part of its logic, but I don't know what methods to use. I've used the NotesLog class, but its not enough on getting the required information.

This here is a part of my Agent:

```vb
Sub LoadAPMSSUBdoc(Rname As Variant, directory As Variant, Datef As Variant)
Dim session As New NotesSession
Dim Tdoc As NotesDocumentCollection
Dim dateTime As New NotesDateTime ("01/01/2000")
Dim GDate As Variant
Dim LocView As notesview
Dim LocDoc As notesdocument
Dim subsidiary As String

Print "Loading APMSSUB - Other Staff Information"

Set session = New NotesSession 
Set cdb = session.CurrentDatabase
Set LocView = cdb.GetView("LsvLocationProfile")
Set LocDoc = LocView.getfirstdocument
StaffServerName = LocDoc.Z_ExtServer(0)

 'SearchFormula$ = "Select Form = ""dfOther""  & @Date(s_Created) != @Date(@Today) "

If (upj = True) And (upg = True) Then
    SearchFormula$ = "Select Form = ""dfOther"" "
ElseIf (ibmmy = True) Then
    SearchFormula$ = "Select Form = ""dfOther"" & L_Employee = ""UPJ"" "
Else
    SearchFormula$ = "Select Form = ""dfOther"" & L_Employee = ""UPG"" "
End If

Set Tdoc = cdb.Search( SearchFormula$, DateTime, 0 )  
If Tdoc.Count <> 0 Then
    Call Tdoc.RemoveAll(True)          
End If

 'Get an unused file number
file_no% = Freefile()
Open (Trim(directory + "apmssub.txt")) For Input As file_no%      

Set db = Session.CurrentDatabase

Select Case Datef
Case "DMY" : Cdatf = "dd/mm/yyyy"
Case "MDY" : Cdatf = "mm/dd/yyyy"
Case "YMD" : Cdatf = "yyyy/mm/dd"
Case Else : 
    Print "LoadAPMSSUBdoc - Unknown system date format"          
    Exit Sub
End Select

Do While Not Eof(file_no%)
    Line Input #file_no%, tmp

    SerialNo = Trim$(Mid$(tmp,1,6))
    Initial = Trim$(Mid$(tmp,239,3))

    HQualification = Strconv(Trim$(Mid$(tmp,8,30)),3)
    Major = Strconv(Trim$(Mid$(tmp,38,40)),3)
    Inst = Strconv(Trim$(Mid$(tmp,78,50)),3)
    If Trim$(Mid$(tmp,128,8)) = "" Then
        GDate = Null               
    Else
        GD1 = Setdate(Trim$(Mid$(tmp,128,8)), "mm/dd/yy", Datef)               
        GDate = Cdat(Format(GD1, Cdatf))
           'Datenumber ( Val(Trim$(Mid$(tmp,134,2))) , Val(Trim$(Mid$(tmp,131,2))) , Val(Trim$(Mid$(tmp,128,2))) ))
           'Print GDate
    End If

    OB = 0
    For i = 4 To 0 Step -1               
        x1 = 137 + (i * 12)
        x2 = 139 + (i * 12)

        temp = Trim$(Mid$(tmp,x1,1))
        If temp <> "" Then
            Redim Preserve Prate(OB)
            Redim Preserve Pdate(OB)
            Prate(OB) = temp
            PD1 = Setdate(Trim$(Mid$(tmp,x2,8)), "mm/dd/yy", Datef)               
            Pdate(OB) = Cdat(Format(PD1, Cdatf))
                'Datenumber ( Val(Trim$(Mid$(tmp,x2+6,2))) , Val(Trim$(Mid$(tmp,x2+3,2))) , Val(Trim$(Mid$(tmp,x2,2))) ))
            OB = OB + 1
        End If
    Next                   

    If OB = 0 And Trim$(Mid$(tmp,185,1)) = "" Then
        Redim Preserve Prate(OB)
        Redim Preserve Pdate(OB)
        Prate(0) = ""
        Pdate(0) = Null
    End If

    AB = 0
    For i = 0 To 3                
        x1 = 198 + (i * 10)

        temp = Trim$(Mid$(tmp,x1,10))
        If temp <> "" Then
            Redim Preserve AAmt(AB)
            AAmt(AB) = Val(temp)
            AB = AB + 1
        End If
    Next                   

    If AB = 0 And Trim$(Mid$(tmp,198,10)) = "" Then
        Redim Preserve AAmt(AB)
        AAmt(0) = Null
    End If

    subsidiary = Filter(CStr(SerialNo))
    If (subsidiary = "UPJ" And upj = True) Or (subsidiary = "UPG" And upg = True) Then


    Set doc = New NotesDocument(db)
    doc.Form = "dfOther"
    doc.L_Employee = subsidiary
    doc.E_StaffSerialNo_1 = SerialNo
    doc.E_PBCRating = Prate
    doc.E_PBCDate = Pdate
    doc.E_AdjAmt = AAmt
    doc.E_HQualification = HQualification
    doc.E_MajorSubject = Major
    doc.E_InstituteName = Inst
    doc.E_GraduateDate = GDate
    doc.E_Initial = Initial
    doc.s_created = Now
      'doc.G_AuthorDisp = "Management SGP"
    doc.G_AuthorDisp = Rname
    Call doc.Save (True, True)      
    End If
Loop

Close file_no% 
Print "Other information imported"

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't see `NotesLog` class in your code. What went wrong when you tried to use it? Please post your current logging code.

Comment: Why do you open a duplicate and do not continue your original one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18715397/lotus-domino-create-import-log/18716335#18716335

Comment: @TorstenLink, sorry about that, I've posted a wrong question, coz of the detailed info needed. By the way, I'm lacking knowledge about NotesLog, coz I don't know exactly it's structure. I only did the log and check the agent's log info on the view.

Comment: I still don't see NotesLog in your code.  You need to update the question to show the code you have tried to use, and you need to tell us what you want to happen, and you need to tell us what actually happened.

Comment: @drayl: Another small suggestion, use proper language when posting/comemnting. Using "coz" makes you sound like a 14 year old, not like a professional programmer. It is spelled "because". You can also -- in some circumstances -- use "since" instead, to avoid repeating "because" multiple times in a paragraph.
Just a hint to come across in a better way.

Comment: Thank you all for your informative comments and suggestions, all helps me well. I have seen my mistakes and short comings and came up with an idea on how to do it. I'll post it as answer to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to construct a sub function inside the agen that will create a document to store the logs upon import:

```
Sub createLog
Dim logdoc As NotesDocument
Dim db as notesdatabase
Dim log As String   


Dim nitem As NotesItem

Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
Set logdoc = db.CreateDocument
logdoc.Form = "ImpLog"
logdoc.ImpRecords = ""
Set nitem = logdoc.Getfirstitem("ImpRecords")
log = CStr(s_countSave) + " document(s) from textfile1 imported; " + "and" + CStr(s_uncounted) + " document(s) was not imported successfully " 


Call nitem.Appendtotextlist(log)
Call logdoc.Save(True, True)

End Sub
```

On the sub function of import agent, create a variable before the loop and set it to `0`:

```
s_countAll = 0
s_countSave = 0
s_uncounted = 0
Do While Not Eof(file_no%)
```

and at the end of the loop add the following code:

```
Call doc.Save (True, True)  
        s_countSave = s_countSave + 1       
    End If
        s_countAll = s_countAll + 1
    Loop
        s_uncounted = s_countAll - s_countSave
```

Hope this help.